# Why does this constraint have differing behaviors in these separate instances?

Tags: haskell, types, type-families, type-level-computation

I made two type families:

```
{-# Language KindSignatures, DataKinds, TypeOperators, TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts #-}

import Data.Kind

type family All (c :: Type -> Constraint) (xs :: [Type]) :: Constraint where
  All c '[] = ()
  All c (x ': xs) = (c x, All c xs)

type family Is (f :: Type -> Type) (x :: Type) :: Constraint where
  Is f (f _) = ()
```

Now I would like to combine the two type families to check if all members of a type level list are maybes.  Here's how I would do this:

```
All (Is Maybe) tList
```

Now if I attempt to test this with the following:

```
f :: (All (Is Maybe) '[Maybe Bool]) => a -> a
f = id
```

I get a compilation error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( familyTest.hs, interpreted )

familyTest.hs:12:6: error:
    • The type family ‘Is’ should have 2 arguments, but has been given 1
    • In the type signature:
        f :: (All (Is Maybe) '[Maybe Bool]) => a -> a
   |
12 | f :: (All (Is Maybe) '[Maybe Bool]) => a -> a
   |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Based on this I would think that I'm missing an argument to `Is`.  My first thought is this has something to do with currying.  Perhaps type families lack partial application.  However when I go to figure out what I am missing something strange happens.  First I check the kinds of all the basic components:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( familyTest.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*Main> :k All
All :: (* -> Constraint) -> [*] -> Constraint
*Main> :k Is
Is :: (* -> *) -> * -> Constraint
*Main> :k Maybe
Maybe :: * -> *
*Main> :k Bool
Bool :: *
```

Nothing here is out of order, so I start putting things together:

```
*Main> :k Is Maybe
Is Maybe :: * -> Constraint
```

This is a bit curious, `Is Maybe` has the kind `Type -> Constraint`.  I would expect this but the error earlier was telling me I was putting the wrong number of arguments to `Is`.  Now we try passing this to `All`:

```
*Main> :k All (Is Maybe)
All (Is Maybe) :: [*] -> Constraint
```

Surprisingly this also works without error, even though we should expect it to.  The last thing to try is to complete the constraint:

```
*Main> :k All (Is Maybe) '[Maybe Bool]
All (Is Maybe) '[Maybe Bool] :: Constraint
```

And it works, despite the complaint from the compiler earlier about this exact statement, this statement now appears to be a valid constraint.  I still get the same error when I compile the original code.

So at this point I started simplifying the code so that I could isolate the behavior.

```
type family App (c :: Type -> Constraint) (x :: Type) :: Constraint where
  App c x = c x

type family IsBool (x :: Type) :: Constraint where
  IsBool Bool = ()

f :: (App IsBool Bool) => a -> a
f = id
```

This still results in a similar error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( familyTest.hs, interpreted )

familyTest.hs:19:6: error:
    • The type family ‘IsBool’ should have 1 argument, but has been given none
    • In the type signature: f :: (App IsBool Bool) => a -> a
   |
19 | f :: (App IsBool Bool) => a -> a
   |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Which does not manifest when I attempt to inspect it with `:k`

```
*Main> :k App IsBool Bool
App IsBool Bool :: Constraint
```

What is going on?

Comment: In Haskell, at the moment, type-level lambdas / partial application of type families are not allowed. Arguments of kind `* -> *` must be `data` or `newtype` type constructors (possibly partially applied). `:k` is too permissive and does not show the full story.

Comment: @chi Why does `:k` even allow it?  It very much seems that `:k` is performing partial application.

Comment: I have no idea why `:k` accepts that. My guess is: it's very convenient to ask `:k Is` and get the kind of `Is`, even if `Is` is not fully applied. This helps the programmer in crafting a full application of `Is`. To get this, we allow partial application in `:k`. IMO, it should only be allowed at the top level, and never allowed elsewhere e.g. `:k F Is` should fail no matter what `F` is. It would also help if we had a kind for constructors like `* -> *` and another for type families like `* ~> *` so to mitigate the confusion.

Comment: This [GHC proposal](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/52) to lift this restriction might help you work out what is going on. There is good information on how type constructors differ from type families in Richard's thesis (chapter 4 I think) both in what you can do currently, and what we should be able to do in the future.